# How do I logout from Azure AD without any interactive pop ups

Tags: java, azure, oauth, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have a legacy Java application ( Java 1.5 ) that logs in to Azure AD.

The process is a bit convoluted but basically we invoke a browser that uses MSAL JS library to log in to Azure AD and then I am given the resulting tokens. I have access to all the JWT that I was sent when we logged in the browser, eg the Identity Token.

I now need to logout, I invoke the logout URL ( via a browser ) but it comes up with a popup that asks me to choose which account I wish to logout. But what we need is to specify which account to logout and avoid a popup window that the user may ignore or cancel.

Note that MSAL library for Java does NOT work with Java 1.5, but if needed I can call a separate Java process that can use MSAL for Java ( more of the convoluted process I referred to above ).

I suspect that we may need to do some direct OAuth API HTTP calls.

Any thoughts or suggestions ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I don't think there is an API to log out. It's always interactive. There might be a way to specify the account when logging out so the user would not need to choose.